# How to use CoreUI Admin Template with my Flask Application

Tags: flask

I am looking to  use CoreUI admin template (http://coreui.io/) in my Flask web application, but I am not sure how to use it.

I checked its documentation, it says to install NodeJS and stuff which I don't know and can't get it to work.

My question is how to use CoreUI admin template with my flask app and how much it will help me create layout for my website.

Comment: question too broad, what have you done so far, with what exactly you need help with?

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly. I have already created flask application. Python backend with mysql database, i am using HTML template i created on my own using bootstrap 3, jinja. I am using flask as web framework. In short i have ready web application but now i want to change say theme of the site. I found Core UI template more suitable to what i actually want. I am using jinja so i just want my output to reflect in CoreUI template. I hope this clarifies my situation. If you want code let me know. PS: I don't know Node.js, bower or Gulp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Just generate Flask project
2. Create js, css and images on static folder add core-UI files there
   or modify the Gulp file coming with project to add them there
3. Install Flask-Bootstrap so that you can easily use this stuff with Jinja2 templates.

I created an example demo in in 5 minutes I haven't updated all the project paths so it's not fully working.

Just to `git clone https://github.com/HintikkaKimmo/Flask-Core-UI`
then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`
and theb `bower install`

All of this expects that you have python3 and Bower installad

Example repo at https://github.com/HintikkaKimmo/Flask-Core-UI

Comment: Hi, Thank you for prompt response. Is it must to use bower? I mean I am OK with points 1, 2 & 3 you have mentioned and copying CoreUI file from Git but I don't know anything about bower or how to use it with flask python. Can I just use HTML & CSS files and edit them in note pad? If you refer to CoreUI website they are asking to install Node.js, Grunt & Bower. What would installing these packages do? Sorry but I know nothing about these 3. I also don't know Saas. I know CSS. PS: I have learned web development on my own without any formal training of any kind. Computer or IT is not my field.

Comment: There is no real must for using Bower, there was just already bower file so I thought that would be easier. Ther is no reason you could not just copy the HTML files.

Comment: Bower, Grunt, Gulp are all just package managers and build tools. Bower is basically a tool to make installation and updating front end package easier